# How to sort and get max score for each name from 3 array of objects in JavaScript and assign it and the missing keys and values to another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to sort and get max score for **each** `name` from 3 array of objects in javascript and assign it and the missing keys and values to another array?

I want to sort the arrays `test1`, `test2`, `test3` and get the max score for each student and assign it and the missing keys and values to the array `results` as an object like:

```
results = [{name: name, age: age score: score}]
```

With the following code I am able to get the object with the highest score like:

```
resutls = [
       { name: 'sam', age: 15, score: 30 }
    ]
```

```js
const test1 = [
        { name: 'vikash', score: 1 },
        { name: 'krish', score: 2 },
        { name: 'kunz', score: 3 },
    ];
    const test2 = [
        { name: 'kunz', score: 0 },
        { name: 'vikash', score: 5 },
        { name: 'krish', score: 6 },
        { name: 'sam', age: 15, score: 30 },
    ];
    const test3 = [
        { name: 'krish', score: 7 },
        { name: 'kunz', age: 10, score: 8 },
        { name: 'vikash', score: 10 },
        { name: 'sam', score: '' },
    ];

    const topScore = (...arrays) => {
        let result = [...arrays].flat().reduce((max, obj) => {
            return max.score < obj.score ? obj : max;
        });
        return [result];
    };

    console.log(topScore(test1, test2, test3));
```

The `results` array should look like this at the end of it ..

```
resutls = [
   { name: 'vikash', age: '', score: 10 },
   { name: 'sam', age: 15, score: 30 },
   { name: 'krish', age: '', score: 7 },
   { name: 'kunz', age: 10, score: 8 },
]
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly in that expected result is supposedly “sorted”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by name and get all values from the object with the max score objects.

```js
const
    test1 = [{ name: 'vikash', score: 1 }, { name: 'krish', score: 2 }, { name: 'kunz', score: 3 }],
    test2 = [{ name: 'kunz', score: 0 }, { name: 'vikash', score: 5 }, { name: 'krish', score: 6 }, { name: 'sam', age: 15, score: 30 }],
    test3 = [{ name: 'krish', score: 7 }, { name: 'kunz', age: 10, score: 8 }, { name: 'vikash', score: 10 }, { name: 'sam', score: '' }],
    result = Object.values([...test1, ...test2, ...test3].reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r[o.name] || r[o.name].score < o.score) {
            r[o.name] = { ...(r[o.name] || { name: '', age: '', score: 0 }), ...o };
        }
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just select the maximum of all the results, to get an array you can build a dictionary of result by name and then select all the maximums:

```js
const test1 = [
        { name: 'vikash', score: 1 },
        { name: 'krish', score: 2 },
        { name: 'kunz', score: 3 },
    ];
    const test2 = [
        { name: 'kunz', score: 0 },
        { name: 'vikash', score: 5 },
        { name: 'krish', score: 6 },
        { name: 'sam', age: 15, score: 30 },
    ];
    const test3 = [
        { name: 'krish', score: 7 },
        { name: 'kunz', age: 10, score: 8 },
        { name: 'vikash', score: 10 },
        { name: 'sam', score: '' },
    ];

    const topScore = (...arrays) => {
        let result = [...arrays].flat().reduce((max, obj) => {
          //check if current item or maximum item contains an age.  
        let age = obj.age || (max[obj.name] || {age: ''}).age
            return (max[obj.name] || {score: 0}).score < obj.score ? {...max,[obj.name]: {...obj , age}} : {...max }
        }, {});
        return Object.values(result)
    };

    console.log(topScore(test1, test2, test3));
```